# Find digit sum of a number in Swift

Tags: swift

Does anyone know how to get the sum of all the digits in a number in Swift?

For example using the number `845` would result in `17`

Comment: Divide by ten, add remainder to the running total, repeat with quotient till zero. What have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses simple integer arithmetic only:

```
func digitSum(var n : Int) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    while n > 0 {
        sum += n % 10 // Add least significant digit ...
        n /= 10   // ... and remove it from the number. 
    }
    return sum
}

println(digitSum(845)) // 17
```

**Update for Swift 3/4:**

```
func digitSum(_ n : Int) -> Int {
    var n = n
    var sum = 0
    while n > 0 {
        sum += n % 10 // Add least significant digit ...
        n /= 10   // ... and remove it from the number.
    }
    return sum
}

print(digitSum(845)) // 17
```

Another implementation, just for fun:

```
func digitSum(_ n : Int) -> Int {
    return sequence(state: n) { (n: inout Int) -> Int? in
            defer { n /= 10 }
            return n > 0 ? n % 10 : nil
        }.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Comment:  This similar to what I need for the second part of my dictionary question from last night.  I have gone a step further and reduced it to a single digit but it does not accept strings. Could you please take a look and suggest variants when you have a minute? Thank you so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512102/sum-integers-using-key-values-from-a-characterint-dictionary-to-one-digit

Answer (score 17):

update:
**Swift 5 or later** We can use then new Character property [`wholeNumberValue`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_ocLvi9_jAhWDHrkGHWtNBlkQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fswift%2Fcharacter%2F3127025-wholenumbervalue&usg=AOvVaw2kTmm9sPodhF_UYLtsU-mb):
**Swift 5.2 or later** We can use the new [Key Path Expressions as Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md)

```
let string = "845"
let sum = string.compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue).reduce(0, +)
print(sum) // 17

let integer = 845
let sumInt = String(integer).compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue).reduce(0, +)
print(sumInt) // 17
```

Comment: Nice. Extremely Swiftesque! It made me look up Array, map and reduce and use it in the playground. I get it now.  Worth studying. Someday you're example here is going to save me some time!

Answer (score 3):

The recursive solution in Swift 3!

```
func digitSum(of number: Int) -> Int {
   if(number < 10) {
      return number
   } else {
      return (number % 10) + digitSum(of: (number/10))
   }
}
```

Comment: @preetam this doesn't work. try `digitSum(of: 56)`  // 2.

Comment: @LeoDabus: apologies, I just thought of sum being recursive till it becomes less than 10 or reaching to one digit. Reverting the my edit.

Comment: @preetam `func digitSum(of number: Int) -> Int {`
    `number < 10 ? number : number % 10 + digitSum(of: number/10)`
`}`

Comment: or `extension FixedWidthInteger {`
   `var sum: Self { self < 10 ? self : self % 10 + (self/10).sum }`
`}`  845.sum // 17

Comment: Recursion is a poor choice. Just use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, and for those who would like to see or understand a math-based approach, here's a real-number function based technique ported to Swift.

This is *not* the most efficient way to tally the digits of an integer in Swift.  I don't recommend using it.  I would personally use @LeoLDbus map/reduce answer to the question, because it is so cool and illustrates a powerful set of Swift features yet short, or @MartinR integer mod/divide answer, due to its utter simplicity and relative speed of integer arithmetic .

*Cocoa and UIKit have the requisite math methods, so you'll probably need to import one of those packages.*

```
func sumDigits(var i : Int) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    var nDigits = floor(log10(Double(i))) + 1
    for var r = nDigits; r > 0; r-- {
        var p = pow(10, r - 1)
        var d = floor(Double(i) / p)
        sum += Int(d)
        i -= Int(d * p)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift4, try below function:

```
func sumDigits(num: Int) -> Int {
    return String(num).compactMap { Int(String($0)) }.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two pieces:

1. `digits`

```swift
public extension UnsignedInteger {
  /// The digits that make up this number.
  /// - Parameter radix: The base the result will use.
  func digits(radix: Self = 10) -> [Self] {
    sequence(state: self) { quotient in
      guard quotient > 0
      else { return nil }

      let division = quotient.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: radix)
      quotient = division.quotient
      return division.remainder
    }
    .reversed()
  }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(
  (867_5309 as UInt).digits(),
  [8,6,7, 5,3,0,9]
)
XCTAssertEqual(
  (0x00_F0 as UInt).digits(radix: 0b10),
  [1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0]
)
XCTAssertEqual(
  (0xA0_B1_C2_D3_E4_F5 as UInt).digits(radix: 0x10),
  [10,0, 11,1, 12,2, 13,3, 14,4, 15,5]
)
XCTAssertEqual(
  (0o00707 as UInt).digits(radix: 0o10),
  [0b111, 0, 0b111]
)
```

2. `sum`

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
  var sum: Element? { reduce(+) }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }

  /// - Returns: `nil` If the sequence has no elements, instead of an "initial result".
  func reduce(
    _ getNextPartialResult: (Element, Element) throws -> Element
  ) rethrows -> Element? {
    guard let first = first
    else { return nil }

    return try dropFirst().reduce(first, getNextPartialResult)
  }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual([1, 2, 3].sum, 6)
XCTAssertEqual([0.5, 1, 1.5].sum, 3)
XCTAssertNil([CGFloat]().sum)
```