# Sum of digits of each elements inside an array of integers (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

In swift 3, how to calculate each integers digits summation inside an array?

Example:

```
var nums = [111,222,333]
```

The output should be like this: `[3,6,9]`

which is the result of calculating: `[1+1+1, 2+2+2, 3+3+3]`

Comment: To double check, is `nums` an array of ints or strings?

Comment: Array of Int @AhmadF

Comment: And thanks for editing my post, newbie here

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466470/find-digit-sum-of-a-number-in-swift

Comment: @MartinR yes it is, but I really need it in an array form of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it as follows:

```
let nums = [111,222,333]

func transform(_ element: Int) -> Int {
    var intsChars: [Int] = []
    for char in "\(element)".characters {
        intsChars.append(Int(String(char))!)
    }

    return intsChars.reduce(0, +)
}

let result = nums.map { transform($0) }

print(result) // [3, 6, 9]
```

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29468466/5501940):

```
func digitSum(_ n : Int) -> Int {
    var n = n
    var sum = 0
    while n > 0 {
        sum += n % 10 // Add least significant digit ...
        n /= 10   // ... and remove it from the number.
    }
    return sum
}
```

you could also achieve the same output:

```
let result = nums.map { digitSum($0) } // [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: All clean and infomative! Thanks!

Comment: @Jayps_T these functions are called "higher-order" functions; Simply, they are functions you can pass as arguments to other functions... As mentioned in the answer, the `map` function is taking a function (`transform`) that contains the logic of returning an int to be transformed. You could check *map*: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map and *reduce*: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce

Comment: Or `let result = nums.map(digitSum)`

Comment: @MartinR Oh! it is kind of weird to me that it could be passed without passing any parameter to `digitSum` :)

Comment: Functions are named closures. Note that you did the same already in `intsChars.reduce(0, +)` instead of `intsChars.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }`